# Generic Alpha Beta Search with C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to design a function template which searches for the best move
for any game - of course the user of this function template has to implement
some game specific functions. What i'm trying to do is to generalize the
alpha beta search algorithm with a function template.

The declaration of this function template looks like this:

```
template<class GameState, class Move,
         class EndGame, class Evaluate, class GetMoves, class MakeMove)
int alphaBetaMax(GameState g, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft);
```

Among other things the function has to:

- Determine if a game has ended: `bool EndGame(g)`
- Evaluate the state of a game:  `int Evaluate(g)`
- Get the possible moves:        `std::vector<Move> moves = GetMoves(g)`
- Make a move:                   `Gamestate gnew = MakeMove(g, moves[i])`

Do you think the function has to many template arguments? Is there a way to
reduce the number of arguments? One idea is to extend the GameState class with members
that evaluate the gamestate or decide if the game has ended. But a alpha beta
search tree contains a lot of Gamestate instances which may leads to
unnecessary memory requirements, thus i like to keep Gamestate small. In general, is a function template actually the right way?

Comment: I'm spontaneously horrified by a template function requiring six different classes, but I'm intrigued by the answers to this one so +1. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define an abstract interface say game_traits and have specialized game_traits implementation for each game:

```
template<typename Game>
class game_traits {
  ...
};

class Chess {
  ...
};

template<>
class game_traits<Chess> {
  static bool endGame(Chess game);
  ...
};

template <typename Game, typename traits = game_traits<Game> >
int alphaBetaMax(Game game, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft) {
  ended = traits::endGame(game);
  ...
}
```

See char_traits in the C++ standard library how it is used there.

Alternatively, you could make them just methods of the Game classes, you don't need inheritence here from some abstract class since you supply it as a template argument. You will just get a, perhaps not so transparent, compile error when your template function tries to access, say game.has_ended(), when no such method exists. This kind of mechanism is also used a lot in the standard template library.

btw, there was a new feature planned for this; Concepts:

```
auto concept GameType<typename Game>
{
  bool has_ended(Game&);
  ...
};

template<typename Game> requires GameType<Game>
int alphaBetaMax(Game game, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft) {
  bool ended = game.has_ended();
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately Concepts have been postponed to a future version of the standard and will not yet appear in c++0x :(

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the abstract interface (game_traits), i have to read about it and how the stl uses this concept.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand the idea, I would aggregate things a bit:

- GameState, EndGame, GetMoves, Evaluate - wrap with single traits type GameStateTraits
- MakeMove is a responsibility of separate algorithm, so GameMovePolicy

I intentionally distinguish traits and policy as separate type. As it's explained in Boost's [Generic Programming Techniques](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html), traits usually carry type information, a description of type properties. This idea fits well to carry static information, a game state. Policy provides behaviour - MakeMove is a part of game dynamic, behavioural algorithm.

```
template<typename GameStateTraits, typename GameMovePolicy>
int alphaBetaMax(GameStateTraits const& state, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding methods to a class doesn't make objects of that class bigger. The methods are stored once for the whole class and used by calls on any instances. Therefore adding the functions to the GameState class would not cause the algorithm to require more memory.

The function template then would only require the single parameter `GameState` and classes used as this parameter would be required to implement the right methods.

A more flexible approach would be to simply use free functions in the algorithm:

```
template<class GameState>
int alphaBetaMax(GameState g, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft) {
   if (endGame(g)) {
     return 1;
   }
   std::vector<Move> moves = getMoves(g);
   // ...   
}
```

Here `endGame` and `getMoves` are dependent names, they depend on the template parameter (since they take `g` as a parameter). Therefore the compiler won't search for actual definitions of these names when the template is declared (it doesn't know yet what type these functions should have since `GameState` is not specified yet).

Only when the template is instantiated the overloads for these functions need to be available that fit the way they are used in the template:

```
struct MyGameState {};

bool endGame(const MyGameState &st) {
  return false;
}

std::vector<Move> getMoves(const MyGameState &st) {
  // ...
}

void tst() {
  MyGameState s;
  alphaBetaMax(s, 1, 1, 1); // uses the new functions
}
```

This way you can adapt any GameState object to your algorithm without having to require special methods on these objects. To avoid polluting the global namespace with these new functions you could put them into their own namespace or a traits class.

So basically you can just leave out the additional template parameters, as long as functions of the correct names and types will be defined once you instantiate the template.

Comment: If i give the functions getMoves, endGame within a namespace, alhpaBetaMax has to know this namespace? Just for clearness: Move has to be a template parameter (it is game specific), because you only declared GameState as template parameter. Till now i don't know about the concept of traits, thanks to all for this hint.

Comment: About the namespace: The ideas was to put these functions inside an `alphabeta` namespace and let the algorithm use the functions from this namespace. Also, when implementing new functions for a new GameState type, put them into the `alphabeta` namespace. This way all the helper function specific to this algorithm are confined in their own namespace.

Comment: I would say it depends, you can either put them in the `alphabeta` namespace or right alongside `MyGameState` (which is in its own namespace, right ?). I would say the more natural would be to put them with `MyGameState` because they extend its interface. Also one should think of providing default implementations for the methods, based on actual member function of the `GameState` concept, to ease development :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd write this as:

```
int alphaBetaMax(GameState *g, Move *move, EndGame *endgame, 
    Evaluate *evaluate, GetMoves* getmoves, MakeMove* makemove, 
    int alpha, int beta, int depthleft);
```

You'd call it as:

```
GameState gs;
alphaBetaMax(&gs, new ChessMove(), new ChessEndGame(), new ChessEvaluate(),
    new ChessGetMoves(), new ChessMakeMove(), a, b, 40);
```

The function itself would delete every pointer but gamestate (I'm assuming that's where your function returns the result, everything else is temporary?).

Now an even better way to do all this is to pass just one class that can do everything, since "make move", "get move", "evaluate", they're all part of the same logic. There's no reason to make 5 different classes, C++ allows you to override more than one virtual function in a class.

Comment: My intention is to design a generic approach like the stl algorithms. But maybe the cons of a generic approach (6 Template Arguments) bring me to an abstract GameState base class.

Answer (score 1):

Too many? Why is it a template at all? This is exactly the kind of 'hitting a nail with infinite hammers' you need to be careful of with templates. Especially something like AI where most problems are largely intractable and performance is crucial.

Comment: I like the idea of solving problems in an generic way like the stl algorithms do. I wrote a alpha beta search for a simple tic tac toe game, now i thought i could make the search generic to use it for other games. For me the template-concept appeared as a promising way.

Comment: What are you making generic, though? If something is a class then it can always be generic in other ways. If you have two types of each of your parameters you will generate 64 templates which will constantly push each other out of cache. A template is only useful when you need infinite genericity on some item and it has nothing in common with other items. Such as a data structure. For this, it has no place at all.

Answer (score 0):

Naive question: shouldn't the gamestate evaluation and "game has ended" decision be additional **methods** (you wrote **members**) in the gamestate class, and thus occupy no additional per-instance memory? Just asking...

Comment: I don't know C++ in depth but i thought everything additional to a class needs some memory. For example the GameState of a Tic Tac Toe game could be represented by only one int.

Comment: No, as soon as you have decided to have a real class (that is, Tic Tac Toe excepted), additional methods do not have any per-instance memory cost. Non-virtual methods are compiled into function calls. Virtual methods are referenced in a methods table, that's true, but there is only one such table for the class. All instances simply use a pointer to it.